# Is It possible to deploy second website on 1 instance in AWS?

Tags: ip-address, webserver, amazon-aws, amazon-ec2

In Amazon Web Services, I have added second Network Interface and added Elastic IP and associated it with secondary Private IP.

How can I deploy my second website on that Elastic IP?

Comment: What web server are you running?  Nginx,  Apache, or something else? It is possible, but the instructions for doing so are going to be different for different web servers.  The fact that you are running on AWS makes little difference.  Cloud provider instances behave just like stand alone Linux servers when it comes to running web servers on them.

Comment: I am using bitnami

Comment: Linux debian server

Comment: It looks like bitnami runs Apache but has the configuration files for it in a non-standard place.